# Why can I not send files larger than 30 MB with telegram on ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

I am using telegram version 2.0.4 on my BQ Aquarius 5.0 Ubuntu Edition. Whenever I want to send files larger than 30MB telegram just stops the transfer once 30MB have been uploaded. When I then leave the chat and re-enter it the file is gone. I thought I could upload files as large as 1.5GB with telegram?

Many thanks for any insights!